# Can I add a public function to objects in JavaScript? How?

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

I'm sure I've worded this question wrong, but I don't know how to explain it well...

I have a vague idea I've read somewhere that I can add methods to objects in JavaScript - by which I mean something like:

```
function Exclaimify(aString)
{ 
    return aString + "!";
}

var greeting = "Hello";
alert(greeting.Exclaimify()) // this shows "Hello!" in an alert box
```

Is this possible? If so, how do I do it?

Comment: Two quick comments: (1) No need for the String(this), you know "this" is a String since you're in a String.prototype function; (2) Don't add anything to Object.prototype or Array.prototype. If you do you can't use "for (var item in array)" syntax any more.

Comment: @John Kugelman: Fixed, thanks.

Comment: Please don't extend your question with your own answer. If you feel like a separate answer is necessary, please post your own answer below.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Assign to it just like it's a variable. Then you can use `this`. Easy!

```
var obj = {foo: "bar"};

obj.someFunc = function()
{
    return this.foo;
}
```

That works great... except! Er, except, not on strings, which are immune to this tomfoolery. (They are completely immutable.) However, there's another way, which is to modify the object's "class" and add the method there. And by "class" I really mean "prototype". JavaScript [doesn't have classes, it has prototypes](http://peter.michaux.ca/articles/transitioning-from-java-classes-to-javascript-prototypes). The syntax to modify the `String` prototype looks like this:

```
var greeting = "Hello";

String.prototype.Exclaimify = function()
{
    return this + "!";
}

alert(greeting.Exclaimify()) // this shows "Hello!" in an alert box
```

Comment: brilliant - exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want to use the technique called [monkey patching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch). That article contains a link to [Duck Punching JavaScript - Metaprogramming with Prototype](http://www.ericdelabar.com/2008/05/metaprogramming-javascript.html) which may help you.

Comment: Thanks. Your linked articles weren't as concise as the accepted answer, but still spot on.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.